# kubernetes multi domain dynamic routing

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Hello I would like to know how to dynamically route multiple domains to different services in Kubernetes, I'm trying to let my users add a domain to their accounts and based on that domain route to a specific service to render their webpage but with their domain. I have no idea where to start and would like to know if this is possible with Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged the question with google cloud my answer is geared towards google cloud.

For HTTP/HTTPS type traffic you can create an ingress resource and the ingress controller(nginx or GKE ingress) will create a HTTP Loadbalancer in google cloud. Then you can provision a static IP to the load balancer. Finally you can configure your domain in DNS to route traffic to that static IP whenever an user hits your domain.

[Guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) on how to create ingress and provision static IP.

[Guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) on configuring domain names with static IP.

Full [guide](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke) on using nginx ingress controller in google cloud.

Here is the architecture of above nginx guide.

[image]

For multi domain use case you just extend the above and configure different domains using the same construct.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that all these services are HTTP(s) based 2 things need to happen:

- an `ingress` object should be created that routes a given domain to an appropriate service (see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)
- proper records must be added to the DNS configuration of a given domain, (proabably a `CNAME` record pointing to your cluster, but it depends whether all traffic is supposed to be handled by your service or just a part of it)

Answer (score 0):

You can create ingress object to route the traffic based on host URL.

```
 Ex:
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: name-virtual-host-ingress
 spec:
    rules:
    - host: foo.bar.com   
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: service1
            servicePort: 80
    - host: bar.foo.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: service2
              servicePort: 80
```